# Alternative Date/Time Libraries for Go

Tags: datetime, time, go

Are there any alternatives to Golang's `time` package? I can't come to grips with its clunky interface and strange way of doing things. The language overall is great, but this part of it just never clicked with me.

Anyone? A really good, thorough tutorial would work too (I have not managed to find one yet)

What I'm trying to do right now is a `goroutine` that updates only 10 times per second (or any variable interval that I set it to). I've not yet implemented it, as the package is not playing nice. Here's the psuedo code.

```
function GoRoutine(updatesPerSecond int) {
    interval = 1000msec / updatesPerSecond

    for {
        if enoughTimeHasPassed {
            doThings()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what parts in particular you find are clunky?

Comment: What part isn't. Even getting something as simple as the time and formatting it can be tricky. It uses a weird mechanism for subtracting time.

What I want to do is simple. I'm writing an application that I wish to update only 10 times per second (at least, that goroutine). The time library isn't helping with something simple.

Comment: Post some (pseudo) code/outline your approach, and what parts you find clunky/hard to reason.

Comment: If I had a question about how to do it, I would write such a question; put ideally I'd like to know if there are alternatives. Regardless, I shall write it down and edit my question.

Comment: `for _ = time.Tick(time.Second / time.Duration(updatesPerSecond)) { doThings() }` -- it's really unclear what you're finding difficult. Alternatives would likely be confusing for everyone else, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you read the documentation at http://golang.org/pkg/time/?

You need to use a [Ticker](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker):

```
func Loop(fps int) {
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second / time.Duration(fps))
    for t := range t.C {
        fmt.Println("tick", t)
    }
}
func main() {
    go Loop(60)
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

then use it like `go Loop(60)`.

Comment: I did read the documentation but I found it to be rather unwieldy. This helps a lot and gave me some insight into how to do these things in Go, thank you.

Comment: @JesseBrands Be sure to upvote answers that help you - and accept ones that solve your issues.

Comment: Are you sure your example is correct? No messages are being printed. Also, if I put it in the main function (for testing purposes), the application crashes, saying all goroutines are asleep.

Correction, it actually only seems to tick once.

Comment: if your `main` exits without waiting, the go  func won't get executed. Also I made a mistake, it's supposed to be `NewTicker`.

Comment: I had a thing that waited for input in the main, so that it wouldn't exit. I already changed it to a ticker myself. Now that it's edited, I can accept this answer. (Even though I wanted a good tutorial or alternative library, this does sort my problem out)

Comment: Tutorial on what exactly? it's rather simple.

Comment: Just the time package. I find it impenetrable, and the resources out there don't help my case. You ever had this API that everyone claims is easy to use, but you just couldn't figure it out? That's the `time` package for me. The ticker is easy enough, but subtracting a date with a duration? I'm lost.

Comment: @JesseBrands for subtracting date with a duration you may use t.Add with negative duration: http://play.golang.org/p/RQJPSp6hbw